# Installing cpan module getting Could not make error

Tags: perl, makefile, module, installation, cpan

I want to install cpan module called Coro for Perl, after typing

```
cpan Coro
```

I get error something like **Could not make: Unknown error**

Here is full log from console: http://pastebin.com/NpXbG2eN

I do not know what is wrong with this.

I found some errors during install:

- error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment fatal error:
- db.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have a file named `cpanfile`? Try adding the dependency there and run `carton install`

Comment: Where is file clanfile located? I tried run "cpan carton" but it doesnt help. Sorry im newbie

Comment: Note: *`Skip ../blib/lib/Coro/Channel.pm (unchanged)`* seems to imply you are working from a "dirty" directory. This can hide information. Set `build_dir_reuse` back to default (`printf 'o conf build_dir_reuse 0\no conf commit\n' | cpan`).

Comment: another log: http://pastebin.com/zREv1zZH

Answer (score 0):

This is relevant:

```
*** It seems you are running perl version 5.022001, likely the "official" or
*** "standard" version. While there is nothing wrong with doing that,
*** standard perl versions 5.022 and up are not supported by Coro.
```

The error you are getting:

```
State.xs: In function ‘coro_derive_padlist’:
State.xs:581:29: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   PadlistNAMES (newpadlist) = padnames;
```

Coro relies on Perl internals that changed.

Comment: So have to I downgrade perl version?

Comment: Your other code perl code might break if you downgrade perl. If you are a newbie, I would not recommend it. Find an equivalent of Coro for perl or another language.

Comment: user3718294 no i cant, i have to use Coro. sorry this is no way. I want/need FIX problem :)